# ctor is ambiguous between single and multiple std::initializer_list ctors on clang and gcc but not msvc

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a nested initializer_list ctor for creating 2D matrixes. Works great. But then I decided to add a simplified row vector matrix (n rows, 1 col) using a single initializer list. This is so I could create a row matrix like this: `Matrix2D<int> x{1,2,3}` instead of having to do this: `Matrix2D<int> x{{1},{2},{3}}`. Of course this required a separate ctor.

Everything worked including in constexpr with MSVC. But when checked using gcc and clang I'm getting ambiguous ctors. Seems pretty clear to me when the lists are nested and MSVC operates exactly as expected.

Here's the code:

```
// Comment out next line for only nested initializer_list ctor
#define INCLUDE_EXTRA_CTOR
#include <memory>
#include <numeric>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <concepts>

using std::size_t;
template <typename T>
class Matrix2D {
    T* const pv;    // pointer to matrix contents
public:
    const size_t cols;
    const size_t rows;

    // default ctor;
    Matrix2D() noexcept : pv(nullptr), cols(0), rows(0) {}

    // 2D List initialized ctor
    Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> list) :
        pv((list.begin())->size() != 0 ? new T[list.size() * (list.begin())->size()] : nullptr),
        cols(pv != nullptr ? (list.begin())->size() : 0),
        rows(pv != nullptr ? list.size() : 0)
    {
        if (pv == nullptr)
            return;
        for (size_t row = 0; row < list.size(); row++)
        {
            if (cols != (list.begin() + row)->size())
                throw std::runtime_error("number of columns in each row must be the same");
            for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                pv[cols * row + col] = *((list.begin() + row)->begin() + col);
        }
    }
#ifdef INCLUDE_EXTRA_CTOR
    // Row initialized ctor, rows=n, cols=1;
    Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<T> list) :
        pv(list.size() != 0 ? new T[list.size()] : nullptr),
        cols(pv != nullptr ? 1 : 0),
        rows(pv != nullptr ? list.size() : 0)
    {
        if (pv == nullptr)
            return;
        for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        {
            pv[row] = *(list.begin() + row);
        }
    }
#endif

    // dtor
    ~Matrix2D() { delete[] pv; }
};

int main()
{
    // Tests of various possible null declarations 
    Matrix2D<int> x1{ };        // default
    Matrix2D<int> x2{ {} };     // E0309, nested init list with 1 row, 0 cols, forced to 0 rows, 0 cols
    Matrix2D<int> x3{ {},{} };  // E0309, nested init list with 2 rows, 0 cols, forced to 0 rows, 0 cols

    // typical declaration
    Matrix2D<int> x4{ {1,2},{3,4},{5,6} };  // nested init list with 3 rows, 2 cols
    // standard row vector declaration
    Matrix2D<int> x5{ {1},{2},{3} };  // E0309, init list with 3 rows, 1 col

#ifdef INCLUDE_EXTRA_CTOR
    // row vector declaration
    Matrix2D<int> x6{ 1,2,3 };  // init list with 3 rows, 1 col
#endif
}
```

E0309 is the MSVC intellisense ambiguous ctor error. However, compiles w/o error
Why are gcc and clang deductions ambiguous? Is there a workaround?

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bxvYGe5E1)

Comment: The question is about possible compiler defects, not about the language standard, thus I have removed [language-lawyer]

Comment: I have no idea which exact set of rules makes it ambiguous but you can differentiate between constructors by extra pair of curly brackets for the first element or omitting them completely: `{ 1, {2}, {3} }` - calls `Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<int>)` / `{ {{1}},{2},{3} }` - calls `Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> list)`.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind Wild. But I'm just trying to simplify a row vector creation so want {1,2,3} to call the non-nested ctor. I get a clear col vector by using {{1,2,3}} which calls the nested ctor. Trying to avoid the extra brackets around each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, compiles w/o error Why are gcc and clang deductions
> ambiguous?

Ambiguous arises here because `{}` or `{1}` can also initialize a single `int`.

> Is there a workaround?

Template your specialized constructor such that `{}` is never deduced to `initializer_list` which still works for `{1,2,3}`.

```
#ifdef INCLUDE_EXTRA_CTOR
    // Row initialized ctor, rows=n, cols=1;
    template<class U>
    Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<U> list) :
        pv(list.size() != 0 ? new T[list.size()] : nullptr),
        cols(pv != nullptr ? 1 : 0),
        rows(pv != nullptr ? list.size() : 0)
    {
        fmt::print("1: {}\n", list);
        if (pv == nullptr)
            return;
        for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        {
            pv[row] = *(list.begin() + row);
        }
    }
#endif
```

If you want `Matrix2D<double> d1{ 1,2,4. }` to work, then you can use `type_identity_t` to establish non-deduced contexts in template argument deduction:

```
// Row initialized ctor, rows=n, cols=1;
template<class U = T>
Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<std::type_identity_t<U>> list) :
    pv(list.size() != 0 ? new T[list.size()] : nullptr),
    cols(pv != nullptr ? 1 : 0),
    rows(pv != nullptr ? list.size() : 0)
{
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sqqzMEbYG)

Comment: Interesting! clang complains about using the single initializer_list for a `{{1}}` argument. See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/ssrodca4z). One would think, given the warning it would be able to choose the more correct ctor.  But, that aside, thanks for your suggestion. Will test it out in my full code!

Comment: Works with a caveat. All the members have to have the same type unlike the nested ctor which checks for narrowing as it has a specific T, but doesn't require the same type. For example: `Matrix2D<double> d1{ 1,2,4. };` fails but `Matrix2D<double> d1{ {1},{2},{4.} };` which makes the same thing works. Ideas?

Comment: @doug See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If we examine the compiler error:

```cpp
<source>:62:29: error: call of overloaded 'Matrix2D(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
   62 |     Matrix2D<int> x3{ {},{} };  // nested init list with 2 rows, 0 cols, forced to 0 rows, 0 cols
      |                             ^
<source>:39:5: note: candidate: 'Matrix2D<T>::Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<_Tp>) [with T = int]'
   39 |     Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<T> list) :
      |     ^~~~~~~~
<source>:22:5: note: candidate: 'Matrix2D<T>::Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<_Tp> >) [with T = int]'
   22 |     Matrix2D(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> list) :
      |     ^~~~~~~~
```

then it kinda tells us with `<brace-enclosed initializer list>` that it doesn't recognize neither the `initializer_list<T>`, nor  `initializer_list<initializer_list<T>>`. Unfortunately, `initializer_list` is a "runtime" construct: its size is not known at compile time.

`initializer_list` has an additional bad property: it matches better than copy or move contructor, so if you accidentally use list initialization when you intended to copy or move-initialize your object, the error will be very confusing :)

Instead, if you know your matrix layout at compile time, you can use some templating with `std::index_sequence` and passing arrays to constructor. If you don't, you can still use `std::initializer_list` and specify the sizes as additional arguments.

Here is an excerpt of what I wrote for myself some time ago trying to solve a similar problem ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/j9zY3h63P)):

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t, typename T>
using enumerate = T;

template <typename Precision, typename NthInnerArrayIndexSequence,
          std::size_t InnerDimension>
class MatrixImpl;

template <typename Precision, std::size_t... NthInnerArrayPack,
          std::size_t InnerDimension>
class MatrixImpl<Precision, std::index_sequence<NthInnerArrayPack...>,
                 InnerDimension> {
   public:
    MatrixImpl() = default;

    // Initialization is row-major. Every inner array is a row.
    constexpr explicit MatrixImpl(
        enumerate<
            NthInnerArrayPack,
            Precision const (&)[InnerDimension]>... nth_inner_array) noexcept {
        // memcpy() is more efficient, but it is not constexpr.
        if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
            ((insert(mat_, nth_inner_array, NthInnerArrayPack)), ...);
        } else {
            ((std::memcpy(mat_.data() + NthInnerArrayPack * InnerDimension,
                          nth_inner_array, sizeof nth_inner_array)),
             ...);
        }
    }

   protected:
    std::array<Precision, sizeof...(NthInnerArrayPack) * InnerDimension> mat_;

   private:
    constexpr void insert(decltype(mat_)& dst,
                          Precision const (&src)[InnerDimension],
                          std::size_t nth_pack) noexcept {
        for (size_t i{nth_pack * InnerDimension}, j{0UL};
             i < nth_pack * InnerDimension + InnerDimension; ++i, ++j)
            dst[i] = src[j];
    }
};

// Base class with routines for any NxM Matrix.
template <typename Precision, std::size_t OuterDimension,
          std::size_t InnerDimension>
class MatrixBase
    : public MatrixImpl<Precision, std::make_index_sequence<OuterDimension>,
                        InnerDimension> {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Precision, float> ||
                      std::is_same_v<Precision, double>,
                  "Matrix only supports single and double precision.");
    static_assert(OuterDimension * InnerDimension != 0,
                  "Both dimensions must be non-zero.");

    using base = MatrixImpl<Precision, std::make_index_sequence<OuterDimension>,
                            InnerDimension>;

   protected:
    using impl = base;

   public:
    MatrixBase() = default;
    using MatrixImpl<Precision, std::make_index_sequence<OuterDimension>,
                     InnerDimension>::MatrixImpl;

    // some useful routines for all kinds of matrices
};

// You can implement a default NxM matrix if you want.
template <typename Precision, std::size_t OuterDimension,
          std::size_t InnerDimension>
class Matrix;

// Square matrix. Reuse base class routines, and add new ones.
template <typename Precision, std::size_t Dimension>
class Matrix<Precision, Dimension, Dimension>
    : public MatrixBase<Precision, Dimension, Dimension> {
    using base = MatrixBase<Precision, Dimension, Dimension>;

   public:
    using typename base::impl;

    Matrix() = default;
    using MatrixBase<Precision, Dimension, Dimension>::MatrixBase;

    // some useful square matrix routines
};

// Can be a Nx1 Matrix specialisation here: a Vector

// 2x2 Matrix
template <typename Precision, std::size_t InnerDimension>
Matrix(enumerate<0, Precision const (&)[InnerDimension]>,
       enumerate<1, Precision const (&)[InnerDimension]>)
    -> Matrix<Precision, InnerDimension, InnerDimension>;

using Mat2f = Matrix<float, 2, 2>;

int main() { constexpr Matrix mat1{{-3.f, 5.f}, {1.f, -2.f}}; }
```

In fact, now you can even use `constexpr` matrices. That is certainly not possible with `initializer_list` :)

Comment: The problem is that the marked lines recognize both initializer_list ctors and can't decide between them. At least for clang and gcc. You can see this by removing either of the ctors and associated instantiations. As for constexpr. I removed the constexpr as not relevant to the question. The code is actually constexpr and it works fine. Also, it's part of a large 2D const matrix class that is entirely constexpr with a full complement of move ctors and assignments. It's also const correct. Only the dynamic memory is not const.